# Can we find this infinite root in term of elementary function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

Let $f(x)=\left(x+f(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{x}$. What is the value of $f(2)$ ?
More precisely,  how to find the value of $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[4]{4+\cdots}}}~?$$

Thank you.

Comment: Recursion up to $1000$ terms yield $1.91164$

Comment: Convergence looks pretty fast. Recursion using only 30 terms and 1000 terms gives essentially same answer $ 1.9116392162458242838833095376406246646085815394062...$ (computing with working precision of 100 decimal places).

Comment: This looks similar to the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html), which is not known to possess a closed form.

Comment: Hmm how is this question "precalculus"?

Comment: I have quite a problem with your definition of the sequence: When defining recursively, you have to define the each by the previous one, and not the other way around.

Comment: $f(2)=f(1)-1$. So what is $f(1)$? I know this isn't the question, but is phased a bit funny.

Answer (score -2):

I got the answer as $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt[3]6}/\sqrt[6]{6}$.I took the fact that among $1,\sqrt[2]2,\sqrt[3]3,\sqrt[4]4,…\sqrt[n]n$,…to infinity ∛3  is the largest one. And I have used the best approximation for this.